# How to add custom view (as a subview) to an UISegmentedControl selected item?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a design request to add the bottom border to active (selected) UISegmentedControl item.

I successfully hide all borders and set the custom background for active/selected state using the attached extension script.

[image: UISegmentedControl with a border active item indicator]

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UISegmentedControl {
 func removeBorders() {
      setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: backgroundColor ?? Constants.Color.mainNavBarBGColor), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
      setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: Constants.Color.mainNavBarBGColor), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)

      tintColor = UIColor.white
      setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
      setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .selected)
 }

 private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
      let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
      context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
      context!.fill(rect);
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      return image!
 }
}
```